# Having trouble trying to get my html to run the for loop Properly

Tags: html, bbedit

```
function displayCaloriesBurned() {

var calburned = 0
var calpermin = 4.2;


for (var i=10; i<30; i+=5){

calburned= i * calpermin;


alert(calburned)

return calburned;


}

}


displayCaloriesBurned();
```

Currently this only portrays the number 42 which is 10 * 4.2, But i want it to portray also the multiples of 15*4.2, 20*4.2,25*4.2, and 30*4.2, what can I change or add so it can do so?

Comment: Just remove the `return` from `for` loop.

Comment: I cant believe i overlooked that, thanks man!